# Exchange server creating dns records automatically. How to stop

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, web-server, exchange

We have 3 exchange / active directory servers.

exchange.queensberry.com
exchange2.queensberry.com
exchange3.queensberry.com

In the domain 'queensberry.com'

Our web server is remote from the network, www.queensberry.com but we want to change it to queensberry.com

The problem is that the DNS on the above servers is automatically creating 'a' records for "same name" with the internal ips of those servers. x.x.1.20, x.x.2.20, x.x.3.20 and there is also my record for the external server.

The problem is that on each lan the ip address being returned is for the local active directory server not the external web server.

Can anyone please tell me why these records are being automatically and how to fix/stop please.

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain controllers always register A records for the name of the domain (queensberry.com) with their own IP address.

This is by design and should not be tampered with under any circumstances. This is primarily required in order for domain members to find the SYSVOL share.

See the following posts which discuss this situation:

[Active Directory: Is it required that the "A" record for a domain point to a Domain Controller?](https://serverfault.com/questions/31686/active-directory-is-it-required-that-the-a-record-for-a-domain-point-to-a-doma)

[Issues with using real domain for Active Directory domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40612/issues-with-using-real-domain-for-active-directory-domain)

[Website and Active Directory domain share the same name](https://serverfault.com/questions/38208/sharing-domain-name-between-domain-controller-and-webserver)

Comment: Thanks Graeme. I find myself going grrrr at the organization that set up our active directory. I can see us changing the website now. But thank you

Comment: You're welcome. You can give them some more 'grrrr' for putting Exchange on Domain Controllers, which is generally frowned upon. ;-)