# Naming Windows Server 2008 domains

Tags: active-directory, domain-name

I am setting up a new Windows Server 2008-based domain and I am thinking about the domain name. Some time ago I read some documentation from Microsoft where they advised to use a .local suffix for "internal", corporate domains so that they do not clash with public, internet-exposed domains. For example, if my company is called Acme and our publicly visible domain (including a web site hosted with a colo provider) is `acme.com`, then our "internal" Windows domain should be named `acme.local`.

However, some time later I read some other documentation from Microsoft where they contradicted this and advised against it.

What do you think? What's the best way to name an internal domain? Any relevant experiences?

**Edit**. It seems that, despite of recommending against using the .local suffix for "internal" networks, Microsoft does impose it on some products such as SBS. Are there any reasons why using .local would be clearly a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Turns out you *can* actually create a non-.local domain on SBS. You need to create an answer file with the desired name, and provide that during the install. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2011/01/21/introducing-the-sbs-2011-answer-file-generator.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

- [MS:Naming conventions in Active Directory for computers, domains, sites, and OUs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264)
- [MS:Considerations for designing namespaces in a Windows 2000-based domain](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285983)
- [MS:Information about configuring Windows for domains with single-label DNS names](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300684)
- [MS:How DNS Support for Active Directory Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759550%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [SF:Issues with using real domain for Active Directory domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40612/issues-with-using-real-domain-for-active-directory-domain)
- [SF:Active Directory: Is it required that the “A” record for a domain point to a Domain Controller?](https://serverfault.com/questions/31686/active-directory-is-it-required-that-the-a-record-for-a-domain-point-to-a-doma)
- [SF:Top level domain for private networks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-for-private-networks)
- [SF:Using .local for internal websites](https://serverfault.com/questions/47087/using-local-for-internal-websites)

Answer (score 3):

The .local domain suffix is not an FQDN and therefore 'non-routable'. This protects your domain somewhat from passing information outside of its perimiter.

For example, a user with a laptop on your internal-only acme.com domain plugs into their home network. It attempts to resolve acme.com and talk to its nearest DC. Your external acme.com is suddently batting off AD-related traffic and that traffic is flowing directly across the internet.

Worst-case scenario is that you pick an internal domain name, and someone else owns that same domain name externally. Now when your users go off-site, their machine attempts to resolve and contact the domain, only to have their traffic being sent to some random company that owns the mysuperdomain.com name out in Timbuktu.

There's also some complications that may arise around internal and external DNS configuration if you choose to use the same name for internal and external domains. Even using a sub-domain of your external domain name (e.g. AD.mycompany.com) can lead to issues with DNS down the line, often in granting internal users access to your resources that are also available externally.

Best practice IMO is using mycompanyname.local for your internal domain, and mycompanyname.com (or such) for external.

Comment: Thanks Chris. In that case, why is Microsft discouraging from using .local now?

Comment: Hi Cesar. I've not encountered this position from MS. Can you link? Thanks.

Comment: From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264: "Generally, we recommend that you register DNS names for internal and external namespaces with an Internet registrar. This includes the DNS names of Active Directory domains, unless such names are subdomains of DNS names that are registered by your organization name.". I remember reading a more explicit argument against ".local" somewhere else in TechNet or MSDN, but I can't remember where!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use .local.  Bonjour for OS X uses .local to do its "magic."  Accordingly, if you use .local for your TLD, you'll need to jump through additional hoops if you ever plan on adding Macs to your network.  .lan is nice and short.

Answer (score 2):

While not reserved .local is used by UPnP SSDP on the microsoft side of the world (apple uses it in Bonjour).  I usually reccomend using .internal (note that .int is reserved)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft actually *doesn't* recommend a .local suffix. They recommend a non-routable, yet unique domain or subdomain under the control of your company. They use copr.microsoft.com as an example.

Comment: I know, I know... that's what I read. Why is Microsoft discouraging people from using the .local suffix if it's an officially recognised non-routable pseudo-TLD? Also, how can I obtain a non-routable, yet unique domain or subdomain under the control of my company? I mean, how can I guarantee that it's non-routable? Thanks.

Comment: In Small Business Server you get no choice over your domain TLD. It's set to .local and that's it. Interesting that they don't recommend this...

Comment: say you own mycompany.com. You can make corp.mycompany.com your internal AD domain and not have it externally routable. Or you can register a domain name and just never put anything externally accessible on it. No DNS enteries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would also discourage the use of .local for the internal domain name. Choose something that's "not routable" but is significant to you and\or your organization.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

Answer (score 0):

If you have desktop linux systems that run AVAHI, you may run into trouble.  I've been tracking [this](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/debian/+source/nss-mdns/+bug/94940) Ubuntu bug for nearly 3 years now where Ubuntu has trouble resolving DNS names that end in .local.  So when I plug my linux laptop into a client network and try 'ssh admin@switch1.client.local' I end up with huge delays.  There is a work-around in that bug, but it's still annoying.  A lot of people have been recommending '.lan' instead of '.local'.  On the other hand, you could always register a valid domain name or use a subdomain like corp.acme.com.