# IIS Seems to Forward Domain/IP to Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

We have a server (Server 1) with Win 2008 that is accessible by RDP and also is set as the primary DNS IP for a domain (example.com). This server is on the same network as an SBS 2008 server (Server 2) which is the domain controller and internal Dns server.
Web requests going to example.com with IP of Server 1 are being passed to Server 2 and served up by IIS from Server 2. 
What causes this to happen?
Is there a safe way to have Server 1 IIS handle the web requests which was our expected outcome?

Example:
DNS entry on ISP:  example.com = 111.111.111.111
Server 1 = 111.111.111.111
Server 2 = 111.111.111.112

Web user goes to example.com in browser, and the page is actually returned from 111.111.111.112?

Answer (score 1):

Your SBS server is a domain controller. In an Active Directory environment, all DCs will automatically register an A record in DNS for the domain name (example.com in your case) with their own IP address.

This has been discussed several times before on SF:

- [Website and Active Directory domain share the same name](https://serverfault.com/questions/38208/sharing-domain-name-between-domain-controller-and-webserver)
- [Active Directory: Is it required that the "A" record for a domain point to a Domain Controller?](https://serverfault.com/questions/31686/active-directory-is-it-required-that-the-a-record-for-a-domain-point-to-a-doma)
- [Issues with using real domain for Active Directory domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40612/issues-with-using-real-domain-for-active-directory-domain)

Comment: Yes - I've seen those. But in our scenario we actually have the internal domain as example.local (which sounds like an ok option) which is handled by the internal DNS server (SBS). The example.com domain DNS entry is actually on an ISP and points to Server 1 but that traffic is going to Server 2?

Comment: You should update the question, this is an important bit of information.